# Find and Replace does not seem to work in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have the following code to search a string and replace it in all deployment.yaml files

it works locally but does not seem to work on Jenkins.

```
def files = findFiles(glob: "**/deployment.yaml")
files.each {
                file ->
                    status = sh(script: """sed -r -i 's,$project.*,$project:$tag,' ./$file.path &> tmp.txt""",
                            returnStatus: true)
                    sh "cat tmp.txt"
                    if (status != 0) {
                        error("Error: string replacement in yaml failed for the file $file.directory")                   
                    }
            }
   
}
```

The tmp.txt file is empty. In any which case the replacement should have worked. The problem is I am coupling this with git add and git commit after this stage and the git does not necessarily add all the changed yaml files.

I tried using `lock` (from lockable-resource plugin) before `git add`, because I thought may be ``git add` has a race condition that I am not aware of. But that did not help either.

Answer (score 0):

You call `sed ... -i ...` which means to make the modificaation "inplace" (aka within the file). This does not produce output as `sed` does without `-i`, when it does output the changed file.

Comment: but it does not do inplace replace either. Because I have a git commit as the following step and git sporadically recognizes changes. So I am not sure if the contents are being replaced and sed as expected works correctly.

Comment: @user2179627 You may check that there IS actually something to change in any `deployment.yml`. If the desired content is already in the file, `sed` won't create change and `git` will see none. If `sed` has nothing to do, it will not produce an error code other than `0`. Together with `-i` it will not produce output. 
There will only be an error code and output, if you pass error-prone expressions or the file does not exist (`$file` may contain spaces). Your checks for `status` and the `cat tmp.txt` are only effective with faulty inputs. `git` will be behave like `sed`, no change - no commt.